# "not a few" vs "quite a few" vs "quite a lot"

Tags: phrase-usage

Compare these sentences

> He had **not a few** kind thoughts about his former employer.
>
> He had **quite a few** kind thoughts about his former employer.
>
> He had **quite a lot of** kind thoughts about his former employer.

I know these sentences mean the same thing, but do they emphasize to the same degree, i.e can I use them interchangeablly?

Comment: They are very similar, but **not a few** is the most understated, therefore the most ironic.

Comment: Related: [Q572004](/questions/572004); [Q513844](/questions/513844)

Comment: 'Not a few' is more formal.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "not a few" is being used idiomatically in your example. **not a few** is unlike **quite a few** in that the latter just means "a large number" whereas **not a few** means  "a large *subset* of those things we've been speaking about".

> Quite a few people prefer coffee to tea. <sup>idiomatic</sup>
>
> Not a few people prefer coffee to tea.  <sup>unidiomatic</sup>

You could be describing a neighborhood's 19th c. houses and add this remark

> Not a few are badly in need of repair.

That is, "not a few" means "many *(of them)*" not simply "many".